# How to modify IVT of a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pic

IVT (Interrupt Vector Table) of a micro controller is a set of address according to which a controller jumps to that particular location to serve the ISR. I am working on `pic18f67j11`, is there any way by which i can change that IVT and i can specify my own memory locations at which controller has to jump.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at chapter 6.1.1 of the [PIC18F87J11 family data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39778e.pdf):

> All PIC18 devices have a total of three **hard-coded** return vectors in their program memory space.

```
0x0000 Reset
0x0008 High priority
0x0018 Low priority
```

These are the addresses where the MCU jumps to in case a corresponding interrupt (or reset) occurs. In other words, these MCUs do **not** have a *vector table* as you might know from other architectures like `x86` where you can set the address of the interrupt handler, and where the CPU than makes an indirect call through these table entries. Instead, the handler addresses are hard wired (similar to the reset vector at `FFFF0h` in the `x86` architecture).

Since there is some space between the addresses, you can implement simple handlers directly at those locations (e.g. reset at 0x0000 - 0x0007, high priority at 0x0008 - 0x0017 and low priority starting at 0x0018).

> Can I specify my own memory locations at which controller has to jump.

The simplest solution is to code a `goto` at the appropriate locations:

```
     org   0x0000
     goto  resetHandler

     org   0x0008
     goto  lowPrioHandler

     org   0x0018
     goto  highPrioHandler

...

resetHandler:
; MCU jumps here for reset
...
     retfie

lowPrioHandler:
; MCU jumps here for low priority interrupts
...
     retfie

highPrioHandler:
; MCU jumps here for high priority interrupts
...
     retfie
```

This wastes some programm memory at the lower 0x18 addresses - you could still implement some parts of the handlers there, like context saving, if you are low on program memory space.